# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, rest, mongoose

I'm trying to make a RESTful route to add a new product to a mongoDB using mongoose, but while trying to do so I face an error - `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"`

another line: `reason: BSONError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer` followed by a very large object having various properties.

This is the route handler to get to the form to add a new product -

```
app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('products/new')
})
```

And in the products/new.ejs file, I'm just trying to show a heading to see if it works or not, but it doesn't. (The exact dir of new.ejs is - views/product/new.ejs)

I'm not sure which line of code is causing this error, but before adding the route mentioned above the code was working perfectly fine. But to give more info about the code, I'm handling two more routes before this -

```
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    const allProducts = await Product.find({})
    res.render('products/index', { allProducts })
})

app.get('/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    const product = await Product.findById(id)
    res.render('products/show', {product})
})
```

I didn't try to change anything in these two routes, since, the code works properly for them. The error is shown only when I visit /products/new.
Please help me understand the reason and a possible solution for this error.

Comment: Do you have a document with `_id: "new"`? Or are you assigning that "string" to an `_id` somewhere?

Comment: @Pipe, No the documents in the db looks like this- [link](https://shorturl.at/fjzLR) , where _id was automatically assigned by mongo.

Comment: Looks to me like the `/new` stuff is getting sent to the place to get by `:id` and therefore the `"new"` characters from the URL are being interpreted as the value to search for (leading to the conversation failure since those three characters don't make a valid ObjectId)

Comment: @user20042973 Yes, this was causing the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reorder your route handlers so that the /products/new route comes before the /products/:id